# Angular 2 calling jQuery after rendering elements - after consuming API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

My Angular2 app consumes a RESTful API and then creates a bunch of `<select>` elements based on the result. I'm trying to call a jQuery function on these `<select>` elements, but it looks like the jQuery function executes too late. I tried putting the function in `ngAfterContentInit` but that didn't work. Putting it in `ngAfterViewChecked` froze my browser.

After the page has rendered, if I paste the jQuery function into the console, everything works, so I know that my function and everything are functional. Their order is just probably messed up or something.

In my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getAll().subscribe(
           data => this._data = data,
           error => this._error = "invalid.");
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  $("select").select2(); // <--- jQuery function I need to execute after rendering
}
```

In my template:

```html
<select *ngFor="let d of _data">...blah blah</select>
```

Comment: How about calling ` $("select").select2();` in the subscribe?

Comment: No luck unfortunately..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
@ViewChild('select') selectRef: ElementRef;
constructor(private myService: MyService, private ngZone: NgZone) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.options = data;
    // waiting until select options are rendered
    this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
      $(this.selectRef.nativeElement).select2(); 
    });
  });
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/hbwA5y5giVJmVsqMIMpM?p=preview)**

Comment: But wouldn't this only affect 1 `<select>` element? What if I had multiple?

Comment: Yeah it is only for select that is populated from service. If you want to apply it to all select then use your jquery selector