# How to observe when a view update has been completed based on a model change in Angular 2

Tags: angular, materialize

I have an ng2 app in which content is being pulled asynchronously from a backend system to inject into a variety of different material based components. In one case, I am trying to create several carousel views from that content.

For example my api responds with something like:

```
{
categories : [
  {name: "sports", content : [{id: 1, title: "some text", description: "more text"}]
]
}
```

I will be creating several carousels, one for each category which are using http://materializecss.com/carousel.html, nothing crazy.

The issue I have is there does not seem to be an appropriate lifecycle event to wire into that will let me know my content from that async call has been rendered - resulting in the creation of several carousels in the dom against which I then need to call a jQuery initialization.

What event will let me know when data from my async request has been marshaled into the dom?

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938422/angular-2-calling-jquery-after-rendering-elements-after-consuming-api

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look up [Angular LifeCycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

> `ngOnChanges() {}`
>   It could be helpful, If data is bind to the component (look [@Input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html))
>
> On JSON received, [`EventEmitter()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html) could be use to `emit` the $event and then subscribe to it in the component

Answer (score 1):

Try using lifecycleEvent "AfterViewChecked"

```
export class whateverClass implements AfterViewChecked{
ngAfterViewChecked() {
 //logic goes here 
}
}
```