# Is there a "correct" way to run jQuery functions after an Component is loaded in Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I **have** to use [jQuery-Knob](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob) in a custom component. After a lot of search and try/miss attempts the only way in how I was able to init my Knob was wrapping the `jQuery` function inside a `setTimeout` with 0 seconds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453231/1255819) answer says.

```
constructor() {
    console.log('Hello SsdKnob Component');

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".dial").knob();
    }, 0)
}
```

But if feels kind of hacky and maybe inestable? (I not sure if I will have problems because of some kind of racing conditions).

Is there a better/recommended way to do this?

I have tried without success:

```
ionViewLoaded() {
     $(".dial").knob();

}
```

and

```
AfterViewInit() {
    $(".dial").knob();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AfterViewInit() {` should be

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
```

alternatively you can also use

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
```

which is run after the view **and** projected content is ready.

If `jQuery-Knob` does some async initialization, this might not be enough. Then you should check if the component emits an event when it's done initializing itself. `setTimeout()` should be the last resort.

Comment: Oh my... I have use the title of the documentations title of the life event. Thank you!